# nvd3.js i can change domain linePlusBarChart

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'am trying to show valueson the y2axis from 0 but i can't. the min value in y2axis is 12000 and the max 245000, i want show from 0

this is the relevant code

```
# get the max value
maxValue = _.reduce(series_2nd.values, ((n, m) -> Math.max(m.y, n)), -1)

# ...   
nv.addGraph ->
    chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
    chart.color(d3.scale.category10().range())
    chart.xAxis.tickFormat (d) ->
        d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y')(new Date(d))
    chart.y1Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1'))
    chart.y2Axis.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'))
    chart.y2Axis.scale().range([0, scope.maxValue + 10]);
    chart.margin({top:50,right:50,bottom:50,left:120})
    nv.utils.windowResize chart.update
    d3.select('#' + name + ' svg').datum(data).transition().duration(500).call(chart)
    chart
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do in your code. Especially the last line seems counterproductive.

Comment: i want show values from 0 and not from the min value

Comment: So what is `chart.y2Axis.scale(scaleY1)` supposed to do?

Comment: i think the line `scale = ...` changes the domain of scale and later replace even i tryied other way without success

Comment: The only thing you should need to run is `chart.y2Axis.scale().range([0, maxValue + 10]);`. Note that you need to set the range, not the domain.

Comment: dont work @LarsKotthoff with the `chart.y2Axis.scale().range([0, maxValue + 10]);`

Comment: Can you show us the complete code please?

Comment: You can also do `chart.lines.forceY([0]);`.